# Help in Identifying bicycle from Mozart in the Jungle Show?

Tags: identify-this-bike, television

Can anyone identify this bicycle manufacturer? Bike appears in season 1 of `Mozart in the Jungle` - [the Amazon show](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mozart_in_the_Jungle)

[image]

[image]

[image]

---

Edit - more shots of the bike (SE doesn't like mp4)

https://i.imgur.com/lIKedCz.mp4

https://i.imgur.com/6iCxtkk.mp4

Comment: Is there any specific reason why its important to know?

Comment: I'm looking for a commuter bike and thought this one looked good. Did some research but couldn't identify the manufacturer or the logo.

Comment: That's one of a puzzle, I couldn't find any matches for the head tube badge. [Here's the enlarged version](https://imgur.com/a/NcnXg) just in case. Looks like a modern bike to me.

Comment: I'm impressed you found the head tube badge! It struck me as a new bike. Show is taped in NYC. I'm wondering if its a local bike shop that may do custom bikes?

Comment: There's always a chance its been relabelled for the program, and isn't officially any real brand.    Its a 1x drivetrain with dual pivot rim brakes, so not a BSO at all.  The low attachment of the seat stays looks modern too, so I'm picking a modern commuter bike.

Comment: Products in movies and TV shows often have their real branding replaced by fake companies; the same may have happened here.

Comment: @Romano you might get answers if you work to contact the production company.  Some of them realise the value of social media and contacts.   Or do the twitter @ thing to the actors.  No harm in trying.

Comment: Didn't consider the relabelled bike. That makes some sense. Will see if I can locate the production company. Good idea @criggie. Thanks

Comment: @Romano if you do find an answer please come back and share it.  That's allowed (and encouraged) by SE.

Comment: Looks like a ripoff of the Startrek Starfleet insignia.

Comment: @mattnz I can see the resemblance. I'm wondering if it was an inside joke on the set.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's Tokyobike. You are welcome.

https://www.tokyobikenyc.com/

---

[image]

Comment: Excellent find!     Based on the imagery, looks like their Sport model.   https://www.tokyobikenyc.com/bicycles/sport
Curiously they're either not overly proud of their head tube badge design cos while it looks like the logo above, its only in side shots of bikes.  Also the leather-clad bike lock seems to cover up the one spot on the frame's top tube where the brand name is.

Comment: Nice work, Rodrigo! Welcome to the site. Our short [tour] might help you get the most out of your time here.

Comment: Great Find Maestro!  Thats pretty impressive! Will go check them out. Thanks for all the help everyone!!!!  @rodrigo